# Between A,B,C & D

Tags: prepositions

There are 4 players. And the question goes:

Who is the best player "between" Jenny, Sam, David, and Lucy?

Is the use of "between" correct after each names? Or if not, what is appropriate?

Comment: FYI, people also have strong opinions on the presence or absence of a comma before the last "and": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma. I see you tried to make everyone happy by using two different conventions in the title and in the body of the question. :)

Comment: @Frederico - I see it more as displeasing everybody as 'everybody' will consider there to be one "incorrect" use, as opposed to being consistent and displeasing only half of the audience. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, *between* can be used without loss of understanding

> Who is the best player *between* Jenny, Sam, David, and Lucy?

However, *between* is usually used in binary choices

> Please choose *between* A or B.

*Among* is more often used when choosing from a related "group"

> *Among* the car manufacturers: Ford, Audi, Volvo, which do you think is best?
>
> *Among* your choices are: watching tv, going bowling, or going swimming.
>   You can choose *between* watching tv, going bowling, or going swimming.

Also acceptable and understandable is

> *Between* watching tv, going bowling, or going swimming, which would you prefer?

Using *between* among more than two choices tends to be more informal.

Comment: *Amoung* is an archaic spelling of *among*.

Comment: I edited from "amoung" to "among". While some web pages claim that "amoung" is an alternative spelling, others describe it as "obsolete" and the OED doesn't even mention it as a historical spelling. I wouldn't recommend _ever_ using "amoung". (Cc @MooseBoys )

Comment: Thank you. And the followings are perfectly ok too? 1. Among A,B,C & D, who is the best player? 2. Among watching tv, going bowling, or going swimming, which do you prefer?

Comment: Yes, both would be used by a native.

Answer (score 3):

I would not say "between" is necessarily wrong, but for a choice within a group I would use [*among*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/among) or amongst.

> 3. in the group, class, or number of ⇒ *ranked among the greatest writers*

Answer (score 3):

*Between* isn't very common when there are more than two choices, but it is understandable.

You could use *among*/*amongst* as the other answers have suggested, or you could consider using *out of*:

> Who is the best player out of Jenny, Sam, David, and Lucy?

And you can also reverse it to say which of the group is the best:

> Out of Jenny, Sam, David, and Lucy, David is the best player.

---

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out+of

> *3.* From among: five out of six votes.